# Node.js module - adding link dependency

Tags: node.js, ld, waf

I'm working on a Node.js wrapper module for a colleagues C library. The library is created in Shared Object (.so) form for dynamic linking.

My CPP module file begins with

```
#include "path/to/lib/source/lib.h"
```

and is built with the following wscript

```
def set_options(ctx):
    ctx.tool_options('compiler_cxx')

def configure(ctx):
    ctx.check_tool('compiler_cxx')
    ctx.check_tool('node_addon')
    ctx.env.append_value('LINKFLAGS', ['-l:lib.so', '-L/path/to/lib.so/'])

def build(ctx):
    t = ctx.new_task_gen('cxx', 'shlib', 'node_addon')
    t.source = ['module.cpp']
    t.target = 'module'
```

When I then proceed to call into my module, which in turns call the library, i get the following error:

```
node: symbol lookup error: <path/to/module.node>:
undefined symbol: <name of library call>
```

I tried dumping the dependencies of the module with 'ldd module.node' and I got a little suspicious as it doesn't mention my .so file.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if the dynamic linker can find your library? Try adding the library path to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. You can run this in the shell before you invoke Node with your test script:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/lib.so/
node test-script.js
```

(On a Mac, that would be `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.)